# Android: Having issues saving encrypted username/password

Tags: java, android, encryption

I have the following class I use to store encrypted preferences to use with my application (using interface with 3rd part site which does not support OAuth)...

```
public class CryptoTranslator {
private static SecretKey SEC_KEY;



/**
 * @return the sEC_KEY
 */
public static SecretKey getSEC_KEY() {
    return SEC_KEY;
}

public static String getSEC_KEY_String(){
    return Base64.encodeToString(SEC_KEY.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}

/**
 * @param sEC_KEY the sEC_KEY to set
 */
public static void setSEC_KEY(SecretKey sEC_KEY) {
    SEC_KEY = sEC_KEY;
}

public static void setSEC_KEY_STRING(String sEC_KEY){
    byte[] key = Base64.decode(sEC_KEY, Base64.DEFAULT);
    SEC_KEY = new SecretKeySpec(key, 0, key.length, "AES");
}

public static void generateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    // Generate a 256-bit key
    final int outputKeyLength = 256;
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    // Do *not* seed secureRandom! Automatically seeded from system entropy.
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGenerator.init(outputKeyLength, secureRandom);
    SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
    SEC_KEY = key;
}

private static byte[] getRawKey() throws Exception {
    if (SEC_KEY == null){
        generateKey();
    }
    byte[] raw = SEC_KEY.getEncoded();
    return raw;
    }

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @param clear clear text string
 * @param mode this should either be Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE or Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
private static String translate(String clear, int mode) throws Exception {
    if(mode != Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE && mode != Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Encryption invalid. Mode should be either Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE or Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE");
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(getRawKey(), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(mode, skeySpec);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear.getBytes());
            return new String(encrypted);
    }

public static String encrypt(String clear) throws Exception {
    return translate(clear,Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
    }
public static String decrypt(String encrypted) throws Exception {
    return translate(encrypted,Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
    }

}
```

So now I have encrypted and stored the data. Now I want to pull it out...

```
            String secString = settings.getString(SEC_KEY, null);
    if (secString == null) {
        try {
            CryptoTranslator.generateKey();
            settings.edit()
                    .putString(SEC_KEY,
                            CryptoTranslator.getSEC_KEY_String()).commit();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        CryptoTranslator.setSEC_KEY_STRING(secString);
    }
    try {
        getUserNamePassword();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.i("Preferences",
                "There was an issue getting username and password");
        isStored = CRED_STATUS_DEF;
    }
            ...
            private static void getUserNamePassword() throws Exception {
      isStored = settings.getBoolean(CRED_STATUS, CRED_STATUS_DEF);
      if (isStored) {
        if (settings.contains(USERNAME_KEY))
            username = settings.getString(USERNAME_KEY, "");
        if (settings.contains(PASSWORD_KEY))
            password = settings.getString(PASSWORD_KEY, "");
      }
      isUsernamePasswordValid();
      if (isStored) {
        String username2 = CryptoTranslator.decrypt(username);
        Log.d("Security", "Username encrypted");
        String password2 = CryptoTranslator.decrypt(password);
        username = username2;
        password = password2;
        Log.d("Security", "Password encrypted");
      }
        }
```

But this gives me the following error....

> javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption

Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

**Update**

Ok per the response I went ahead and changed my code to the following...

```
public static final int IV_LENGTH = 16;
private static final String RANDOM_ALGORITHM = "SHA1PRNG";
...
    private static String translate(String clear, int mode) throws Exception {
    if (mode != Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE && mode != Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Encryption invalid. Mode should be either Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE or Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE");
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(getRawKey(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(generateIv());
    cipher.init(mode, skeySpec, ivSpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear.getBytes());
    return new String(encrypted);
}
...
    private static byte[] generateIv() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchProviderException {
    SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance(RANDOM_ALGORITHM);
    byte[] iv = new byte[IV_LENGTH];
    random.nextBytes(iv);
    return iv;
}
```

Now I get...

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted

To try and use hex changed to...

```
private static byte[] translate(byte[] val, int mode) throws Exception {
    if (mode != Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE && mode != Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Encryption invalid. Mode should be either Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE or Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE");
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(getRawKey(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(generateIv());
    cipher.init(mode, skeySpec, ivSpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(val);
    return encrypted;
}
```

This seems to *almost* work (I am getting the .com back) but the chars are still pretty jumbled.
    public static String encrypt(String clear) throws Exception {
        byte[] test = translate(clear.getBytes(), Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
        return new String(Hex.encodeHex(test));
    }

```
public static String decrypt(String encrypted) throws Exception {
    return new String(translate(Hex.decodeHex(encrypted.toCharArray()), Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE));
}
```

*The converting to Hex and back is screwed up here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are a couple of issues with your code.

First is the output of an AES cipher is not character data, you are mangling your ciphertext by trying to put it in a String. When you try to decrypt your mangled ciphertext it is now the wrong length. You need to Base64 or Hex encode the ciphertext if you want to store it in a String and then decode it back in to a `byte[]` before decrypting it.

Second, when you specify just `AES` for your cipher spec Java expands that to `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding`. `ECB` is an insecure cipher mode if you intend to encrypt more than 1 block of data (16 bytes for AES). I recommend you switch to a different spec `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` should be acceptable. Using a mode other than `ECB` will require an Initialization Vector (IV).  The IV should be randomly generated but does not need to be secret, so you can store as plaintext with your ciphertext as you'll need it to decrypt as well. The initialization vector needs to be one block in length (16 bytes for AES). Do not reuse the same IV with the same AES key ever, generate a new IV for each encryption being done.

Finally, if your going to store IV + ciphertext in a third party service I recommend you add a MAC  (such as HMACSHA1). A MAC will ensure the integrity of your IV + ciphertext before you attempt to decrypt it.  A MAC will require a secret key as well, and you should not use the same key you generated for the cipher itself. You can prepend the generated MAC to your IV + ciphertext, so now you are storing MAC + IV + ciphertext.

Comment: Awesome explanation you get the check! Thanks got it working! Not posting code because it is rather long but be careful there is a naming conflict with commons codec which requires you to use Hex.encodeHex instead of the String one.

Answer (score 0):

Android AES client  side + PHP AES server side it will throw this error :)

The solution is:

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

Please search over the internet for the full source code.  I am under NDA and to lazzy to make anonymous my whole code regarding this part, but  I am sure you will find it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I can look over this and I can try out what you are inferring here but I have a question. What do you mean by "server" and "client" side here? I am assuming it has to do with the keys and not the location right?

Comment: Added just to that line now I get "java.security.InvalidKeyException: no IV set when one expected" Trying it in other areas I declare AES.

Comment: The server side ( PHP ) encrypted a string with AES. The Android with a HTTP GET or POST asked that String and decrypted. In our example that was. I don't have the PHP code. We needed to have some modification on PHP code too work properly with Java. Around 1 week was until we figured out why don't want to work the Android + PHP with AES :)